# Mapping dynamic csv file to EF entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dictionary, csvhelper

I have been using EF and using CsvHelper to map testing output directly into db entities for quick storage.  I now have an issue with a performance monitor that tracks cpu cores, port io, and core/port pairing data.  I can have any number of cores and any number of ports, these multiply out in core/port pairing.  The output is in csv format, I have no control over this output format.

I am needing to scan in this dynamic column-sized csv in efficiently to the entity model.  My hope is that I can map the columns to the various tables with minimum of manipulation.

A paired down example of the POCO for the EF:

```
public class CpuTesting
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Socket { get; set; }
    public int Core { get; set; }
    public double ProcessorTime { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<PortCorePairing> PortCorePairings { get; set; } 
}

public class PortIo
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Int64 BytesReceivedTotal { get; set; }
    public Int64 BytesSentTotal { get; set; }
}

public class PortCorePairing
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int CpuTestingId { get; set; }
    public int InteruptPerSecond { get; set; }
    public int DiscardedSent { get; set; }
    public int DiscardedReceived { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CpuTestingId")]
    public virtual CpuTesting CpuTesting { get; set; }
}
```

The massively simplified header row that this maps out to (trust me, it is paraphrased... I am typically dealing in sets of 200+ columns for a single port test, which is why I am hoping to find a better way of mapping).

```
Cpu(0,0) ProcTime, Cpu(0,1) ProcTime, Cpu(1,0) ProcTime, Cpu(1,1) ProcTime, Port(0) BytesRecTotal, Port(0) BytesSentTotal, Port(1) BytesRecTotal, Port(1) BytesSentTotal, Cpu(0,0) Port(0) CoreIntPerSec, Cpu(0,0) Port(0) Discarded, Cpu(0,1) Port(0) CoreIntPerSec, Cpu(0,1) Port(0) Discarded, Cpu(1,0) Port(1) CoreIntPerSec, Cpu(1,0) Port(1) Discarded, Cpu(1,1) Port(1) CoreIntPerSec, Cpu(1,1) Port(1) Discarded
```

Right now the only way I see this is pre-processing the header row to parse the columns out in sets (mapping by index), iterative progression though the csv file.  This has a lot of overhead and would involved mapping and auto-mapping.  The headers change text in multiple places which make the mapping need to key off of substrings in the header.

**CSV header above is pattern example only:**
The included csv header is just a trimmed down pattern of the problem.  If I change brand/model of the port, I get a NEW name for the port rather than *Port*.  The next system being tested may have 12 cores per CPU and/or four ports.  Literally I have a dataset in front of me now with 4 cpus @ 12 cores ea., 4 ports, and with pairing ends up being nearly 1200 columns.

Comment: Did you look at the Fluent Mapping section of the documentation?  Looks like you can generally map a parent/child relationship and specify the header names in your CSV.  https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/

Comment: @EricJ. Yeah, its how I have to manage the normal inputs.  Problem for me is that the header columns dynamically expand.  I have to create associations with cores and ports with properly associated headers.  some of these headers are rough for matching: `\\machine-14\per processor network interface card activity(9, ethernet server adapter)\dpcs queued/sec`